# Can get with jquery session variables? calling a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to improve my English

I have a js look that sent by post even php values ​​which in turn stores these values ​​in a php varible I show my files or extracts from them

index.html 
HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.add-music').click(function () {
         var songNew = JSON.stringify({
             title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
             artist: $(this).attr('data-artist'),
             mp3: $(this).attr('href')
         });
         var songIE = {json:songNew};
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: songIE,
             datatype: 'json',
             url: 'session.php',
             async: true,
             cache: false
         });
     });
 });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <b class="add-music" data-title="chika" data-artist="comppac" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Add to List</b>
        <b class="download-music" href="audios/song-little.mp3">Download</b>

        <b class="add-music" data-title="mediana" data-artist="comppam" href="audios/song-med.mp3">Add to List</b>
        <b class="download-music" href="audios/song-middle.mp3">Download</b>

        <b class="add-music" data-title="grande" data-artist="comppag" href="audios/song-big.mp3">Add to List</b>
        <b class="download-music" href="audios/song-big.mp3">Download</b>
</body>
</html>
```

session.php 
PHP Code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["json"])){
    $jakson = $_POST["json"];
session_start(); 
$_SESSION["playlist"][] = $jakson;
}
?>
```

ok now I want a index2.html or Live index.html Collect the contents of the playlist session variable, I create a test file called recoger.php 
and put the following just to see what is stored 
recoger.php 
PHP Code:

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<br />';
 ?>
```

and shows me the following

PHP Code:

```
array(1) {
  ["playlist"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(111) "{"title":"emo","artist":"a href=","mp3":"/audios/01%20-%20Survie.mp3"}"
    [1]=>
    string(158) "{"title":"Las Voces de L@s del Bosque","artist":"","mp3":"/audios/La%20voces%20de%20l%40s%20del%20Bosque%20copy.mp3"}"
    [2]=>
    string(143) "{"title":"radio novela waO1","artist":"","mp3":"/audios/radionovela%20wagia%20final.mp3"}"
    [3]=>
    string(174) "{"title":"o a La Comunicación","artist":"","mp3":"/audios/Cun%CC%83aunicacion.mp3"}"
  }
```

How I can get these results with jquery ajax live marrow every click that and add a value to the variable array of other ajax session listening to this show immediately

any idea help is welcome thanks

Comment: To get them to your JS, you would want to have a `success: function(m) {//what to do here}` and in PHP, make the array how you want and use `json_encode` before sending it back from the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create ajax call

```
...
$.ajax('getSession.php', {...}, function(response){
...
});
...
```

to Your getSession.php file, which is

```
<?php 
// some code
echo json_encode($_SESSION['playlist']) ;
```

so in ajax callback body use variable response will be Your `$_SESSION['playlist'];`